# Google Pay CRYPTOGRAM_3DS integration for websites

Tags: braintree, google-pay, adyen, react-native-google-pay

I am trying to integrate Google Pay into one of our websites. If I provide only `CRYPTOGRAM_3DS` as an authentication option, the Google Pay button is not getting displayed in Desktop Chrome and even in Android Chrome also. I have read that `CRYPTOGRAM_3DS` is used for the cards that got stored in Android device as tokens. Does that mean that I have to use `CRYPTOGRAM_3DS` only for Android app integration or will it work for web integration also? I really want to understand when we have to use `CRYPTOGRAM_3DS` as an authentication method for Google Pay integration. If it supports for web integration, what are the things that I need to do to really see the Google Pay button with only `CRYPTOGRAM_3DS` as authentication option?

Answer (score 2):

> I have read that CRYPTOGRAM_3DS is used for the cards that got stored in android device as tokens.

This is correct, CRYPTOGRAM_3DS is only available for cards tokenized using Google Pay. This means that it is only available on Android for **both** web and Android integrations on an Android device.

Can you include a sample integration with sample code?